# Fourier transform (their inverse)

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Assume that $D$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f\in C_0^\infty(D)$. Let $a>0$ and let $F$ be the Fourier transform.  Define $$g(x)= F^{-1} (|x|^{-2a} \cdot (F f)(x)).$$ My question is for which parameters $a$ we have  $$g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$$

Comment: You can't really expect that $g$ is supported in $D$. Do you perhaps mean that the restriction of $g$ to $D$ should be in $L^2$? Or do you want $g\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$?

Comment: You right, I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(f)$ is analytic and tends to $0$ faster than any power because $f$ is $C_0^\infty$.
$F$ and $F^{-1}$ map $L^2$ onto itself. So the question is when $|x|^{-2a}$ belongs
to $L^2$ locally (near the origin). Normally this happens when $a<n/4$.
This is necessary and sufficient unless $Ff(0)$ accidentally equals to $0$.

Edit.
Can we relax the condition $f\in C_0^\infty$ ? Yes, we can. Compact support was not really used much. Fast enough decrease will be enough. On the other hand, smoothness was
used substantially, to ensure that the behavior at infinity is good for every $a$.

Comment: And $Ff(0)=0$ means simply that $f$ has zero mean.

Comment: Yes. But in this case, the answer also depends on the multiplicity, that is on the homogeneous polynomial of the lowest degree in the Taylor expansion of $Ff$ at $0$.

Comment: True. I just wanted to highlight the fact that special things happen if and only if $Ff(0)=0$, and this condition has a simple equivalent form.

Comment: @Eremenko, Can we relax from the condition $f\in C_0^\infty$?

Comment: @ Alexandre $r^{-4 a} r^{n-1}= r^{n-1-4a}$ so it should be $n-1-4a>-1$ i.e. $a<n/4$. So you right...